# save cmd output to text file - php

Tags: php, cmd

I am using php file. I run cmd from my php and want to get the output of cmd in a text file.

I type:

```
$output = "";       
exec("cd C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\webclient\\db\\nucleotide && blastdbcmd.exe -entry_batch $text_files_path/NewSeqGi_$OldDatabaseFile$NewDatabaseFile.txt -db $DatabaseName -outfmt %f 2>&1",&$out, &$return_var);
foreach ($out as $line) {
$output .= $line."\n";
}
file_put_contents("$text_files_path/NewSeq_$OldDatabaseFile$NewDatabaseFile.txt", $output);
```

Is there any way instead of using foreach to save the $out in a text file?

when I run my code, it stuck in

```
foreach ($out as $line) {
    $output .= $line."\n";
    }
```

because the $out is very huge.
Any idea?
Thanks.

**Solution**

```
exec("cd C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\webclient\\db\\nucleotide && blastdbcmd.exe -entry_batch $text_files_path/NewSeqGi_$OldDatabaseFile$NewDatabaseFile.txt -db $DatabaseName -outfmt %f > $text_files_path/NewSeq_$OldDatabaseFile$NewDatabaseFile.txt 2>&1");
```

Thanks @DarkBee

Comment: Could try with `file_put_contents($filename, print_r($output, true))` or route to a textfile via the command

Comment: @DarkBee I did not get your point!

Comment: `cd C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\webclient\\db\\nucleotide && blastdbcmd.exe -entry_batch $text_files_path/NewSeqGi_$OldDatabaseFile$NewDatabaseFile.txt -db $DatabaseName -outfmt %f 2>&1 1>myfile.log`